# Uploading to Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have a MySQL application and would like to moved it gradually to Firebase. As a first step I am "dumping" JSON objects made from queries (simple queries over one or two tables) to Firebase. I want to do this on a regular basis, just calling a page that produces an object (from the MySQL using Coldfusion) and as a security rule I should be logged in with a specific Twitter account.

This is the page READING data Firebase http://www.redesign.mobi/fbse/

This is the page in WRITE mode http://www.redesign.mobi/fbse/?up=aktuell

Presently I cannot write because I set write to false in "Security and Rules":

```
".write": false
```

Just for testing I wanted to set the rule that anyone logged in can write

```
".write": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'twitter'"
```

The Twitter auth works properly but it does not prevent a not-logged-in user from writing.

What did I overlook?

Here is the code for auth and writing:

```
      <!--- Auth --->
      var ref = new Firebase("https://shining-fire-8148.firebaseio.com");
      ref.authWithOAuthPopup("twitter", function(error, authData) {
         if (error) {
                    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
         } else {
                   console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
         }
      });

      var qaktuell = new Firebase("https://XXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com/angebote3");
      qaktuell.set($scope.items);
```

Comment: That `.write` rule is the correct way to only allow Twitter-authenticated users to write, so most likely there is something else wrong. Can you post a complete, minimal snippet that reproduces the problem?

Comment: As a separate note, your `qaktuell.set()` currently runs before the user is authenticated. You probably want to put that code in a `ref.onAuth()` handler. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/onauth.html

Comment: The cause of the problem isn't presented here. Hard to help without being able to reproduce the issue. See [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello Frank,
thank you. It helped indeed to produce that snipped so the problem became obvious: I did no put it into on Auth handler as you said in your separate note, stupid me. Thank for taking the time nonetheless. I leave it here as a reference: http://www.redesign.mobi/fbse/index3.cfm